# Create table on a Master - Master config avoiding replication

Tags: mysql, replication

I have a `Master-Master` configuration.

What I want is to create an auxiliary table only for a report project so it's not necessary to replicate it.

Is there a specific way to make this in the `CREATE TABLE` line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The safest approach is to stay far, far away from trying to filter replication... and tweaking `sql_log_bin` on and off is a recipe for replication problems, too.  In a replicated environment, the general idea is that both servers have identical data sets, and to whatever extent they don't, your setup becomes exponentially more complex.

There is an easier and safer approach.

First, create the table, with the storage engine you want, on the server where you want it to store data.

Then, on the other server (where you don't want the table to store data), verify that the definition has replicated and that the table exists, and then:

```
mysql> SET sql_log_bin = 0;
mysql> ALTER TABLE t1 ENGINE=BLACKHOLE;
mysql> SET sql_log_bin = 1;
```

This will change the table to a Blackhole table locally, without replicating that change back to the other master server.  This is something you only need to do once, when you set up the table.  After that, us it normally.

The [Blackhole Storage Engine](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/blackhole-storage-engine.html)...

> acts as a “black hole” that accepts data but throws it away and does not store it.

The server with the blackhole table will still churn through the replicated queries involving that table, but with substantially less overhead (writes to the table will be discarded), and `SELECT * FROM table` will always return... nothing.

You can write to the real table on one server without taking up space or having the data in the table be selectable on the other server.

**caveat:** if you are manipulating data in other tables based on what you have in this table (`INSERT ... SELECT` ... `UPDATE ... JOIN` ...etc.) then you *need* to be using `binlog_format` = `ROW` or abandon this idea altogether, because those queries will not work without this table's data on both masters, if your `binlog_format` is `STATEMENT`, and will not necessarily work reliably with `MIXED` mode either.

Comment: I have a doubt... this won't crash my full replication config right? `sql_log_bin` value 0 & 1 are the specific ones? or they must be `mysql-bin` master value?

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/set-sql-log-bin.html `sql_log_bin` is a session variable that defaults to `1`.  If you set it to `0` it disables binary logging of any statements you issue until you disconnect or set it back to `1`.  The application, here, is to allow you to alter the table without that individual statement getting replicated, because you want the servers to have a table that is identical other than the storage engine.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable binary log in a session and then create the table, use it and the drop:

```
SET sql_log_bin = 0;
CREATE TABLE t(...);
...
DROP TABLE t;
```

Comment: But I want the table alive

Comment: I thought it's gonna be a temporary table. Ok. Then don't drop it. It can stay forever, but each SQL query that mentions it should be prefixed with "SET sql_log_bin = 0;". O

Comment: hmmmmmmm .... sorry for my confusion... either each `SELECT` query must have the `SET` statement prefixed? or only the `CREATE TABLE` line?

Comment: Sorry for being confusing. You don't want any write SQL statement (CREATE, UPDATE, INSERT, DELETE) to get into the binary log. Otherwise it will be replicated to another master and as long as table `t` is missing the replication will break.
You can start a MySQL session that modifies table `t` with "SET sql_log_bin = 0" . That also means any write query won't get into the binary log, which you probably don't want, because you may want to modify other tables within the session.
As you can see what you want to do brings additional complexity, thus not really recommended.